# Why is my webpage scrolling choppy on mobile device but fine on laptop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to fix my webpage scrolling problem. I build my webpage using wordpress elementor but there is this one problem on this particular page. If I scroll down on the area with a lot of text, it seems that it will glitch back up to the beginning of the text after I passed that area for the second time, then it will be smooth.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Try visiting the page on mobile device to view the problem
https://kenwilboy.com/ism/

Comment: I found a article for this problem maybe this article can help : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/08/scroll-bouncing-websites/

Comment: it's quite different, can anyone help me to solve this problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may be new to web performance, as their are many issues going on with your webpage. After running a performance scan with Chrome Lighthouse, the results were alarming, but illuminating:

[image]

Once you run the scan, you can click on each of the labels next to the upward arrow icon and view the details leading to each issue. Raising that score > 70 will greatly improve mobile performance.

Comment: The problem has been resolved, it turns out that the type of animation is what causing it to glitch back, I just change the type of animation in the elementor pro editor and the problem disappear, thank you. 